# Cognos Report Studio - between and ends with syntax

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

I'm trying to create a detailed filter. I have a report which list down the items I need, but would like to further refine it.

```
[DB].[RP] BETWEEN ('XX80150P') and ('XX80220P')
```

The results give me enough information. but there are items which are like 'XX80150P660'. I want to exclude them. So I want to add ends with 'P'.
Can anyone help with the "ends with" syntax please, in addition to the between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know standard SQL syntax?
Add to your condition

```
AND [DB].[RP] like '%P'
```

Comment: Sometimes Report Studio struggles when stacking 'and's.  Try enclosing your individual conditions in parenthesis if you get an error using Alexey's solution.